# Converting unsigned char* to uint64_t

Tags: c

I have converted `uint64_t` to `unsigned char*` using the following:

```
uint64_t in;
unsigned char *out;
sprintf(out,"%" PRIu64, in);
```

Now I want to do the reverse. Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The direct analogue to what you're doing with `sprintf(3)` would be to use [`sscanf(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf):

```
unsigned char *in;
uint64_t out;
sscanf(in, "%" SCNu64, &out);
```

But probably [`strtoull(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoull) will be easier and better at error handling:

```
out = strtoull(in, NULL, 0);
```

(This answer assumes `in` really points to something, analogous to how `out` has to point to something in your example code.)